# IOS: fill a popover with a tableview

Tags: xcode, ios, uitableview, uipopovercontroller

How can I create a popover and fill it with a tableview? I have a button on a toolbar in bottom of my view, and when i push this button I want to show this popover

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create pushviewcontroller and in the pushviewcontroller you have to give the tableview. 
 like this.

```
UIViewController *myPopOver = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyPopOverView" bundle:nil];
//(asper your requirement take thiscontroller as tableview)
popoverController = [[[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:myPopOver] retain];
```

Comment: did you set the delegate and datasource? and call the delegate methods.

Comment: use this.  [popoverController setPopoverContentSize:CGSizeMake(299.0f, 111.0f)];