# How to fill data in UItableview in popover from UIViewcontroller?

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, uipopovercontroller

I think this is an easy question.  I've looked at other solutions but they to miss a key step for me.

[IOS: fill a popover with a tableview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6185507/ios-fill-a-popover-with-a-tableview)

How to shove an array of values into an empty table in a popup?

The data is loaded properly and returned in my variable `listOfFiles`  and the popover successfully launches with an empty table.

Now I'm missing the concept of how to get a reference to the UITableview? in my popover to populate it with data from a plist?

Do I need to add `UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate` to my UIViewController?

```
     //MARK:buttons to save and load defaults
      @IBAction func loadState(sender: UIButton) {

        if(dbg){println("loaded State")}

        //get list of plist files
        var listOfFiles: [String] = getSavedState()

        if(dbg){
          for index in listOfFiles {
            println("file name is \(index)")
          }
        }

//how to shove the data into the table??


        //MARK:idPopupFileTable
        let popoverVC = storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("idPopupFileTable") as UIViewController
        popoverVC.modalPresentationStyle = .Popover
        popoverVC.preferredContentSize = CGSizeMake(300, 200)

        if let popoverController = popoverVC.popoverPresentationController {
          popoverController.sourceView = sender
          popoverController.sourceRect = sender.bounds
          popoverController.permittedArrowDirections = .Any
          popoverController.delegate = self
        }
        presentViewController(popoverVC, animated: true, completion: nil)

      }
```

I've tried many ways but can't seem to get an `IBOutlet` from the `popoverVC` to the table.  I can set up referencing outlets as seen below but cannot seem to create IBOutlet.

[image: popupVC]

Here is what the popoverVC looks like on the Storyboard, there is no direct segue connection to the mainVC.

[image]

[image]

Comment: If I understand correctly, I think you'll need to create and instantiate a new view controller to hold all your data (this will have a table view in it, etc... and you'll probably pass your data to it when you create it) and then instantiate the popover view controller using `init(contentViewController viewController: UIViewController)` passing to it the view controller that will go inside.

Comment: Thanks for the help but I think there should be a way to grab a reference to the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `popoverVC` should have an `IBOutlet` to its table, and should implement the data source and delegate methods. That controller should also have an array property (called `dataArray` in my code below) that you can pass your array to when you create `popoverVC`.

```
let popoverVC = storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("idPopupFileTable") as UIViewController
popoverVC.modalPresentationStyle = .Popover
popoverVC.preferredContentSize = CGSizeMake(300, 200)
popoverVC.dataArray = liseOfFiles
```

Comment: Thanks. I've added to OP, I can't seem to add `IBOutlet` reference?  What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Does popoverVC have a table view as a subview?

Comment: Yes, i'll post an image.

Comment: Can't you control drag from the table view to the popupFileTable.swift file to connect an outlet?

Comment: No, there isn't a separate popupFileTable.  The popup is contained within the UIViewcontroller, the table is contained within the popup. I think maybe I need to change the `popoverController.sourceView` from `sender` to the VC?

Comment: Your storyboard image shows a controller called PopupFileTable. That's what I'm talking about. Is that the popover's contentViewController?

Comment: Yes, I create that in Storyboard and call it with `let popoverVC = storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("idPopupFileTable") as UIViewController` but there is no way to drag an outlet from the table to the UIViewController only internal to the VC as delegate and datasource.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73104/discussion-between-rdelmar-and-g-alexander).